# jScrollPane not working after jquery .load() method

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I am using jScrollPane to create custom scrolls on a div wich has it's content updated through ajax, using the .load() method (jQuery).

It works on the first time the content is loaded into the div, but when I cange contents the div still have the overflow: hidden, so jScrollPane makes no scroll for the new content. I tried clearing the overflow attribute like this:

```
$('#content .text').css('overflow', 'auto');
$('#content .text').jScrollPane();
```

But this makes the content div use the system scroll, not the custom scroll. So I tried this:

```
$('#content .text').css('overflow', 'none');
$('#content .text').jScrollPane();
```

However, I don't believe it exists at all. So I tried actually cleaning the attribute with this:

```
$('#content .text').css('overflow', '');
$('#content .text').jScrollPane();
```

But still had no success.  Is there any other way I can do it?

- I can't clear the whole style attribute because I am using it to set dynamic heights and widths for the div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Per [the AJAX example](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/ajax_example.html), you should simply call `.jScrollPane()` (with appropriate options) once the AJAX call completes to update the custom scrollbars.

Comment: Again, it would be very helpful if you could point us to a webpage demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should actually be

```
$('#content .text').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

Comment: Overflow hidden is what jscrollpane already leaves on the div when I reset the content. I tried "restarting" the overflow hidden also, but still without success.